# PSP X9 - adjust selection size

Tags: selections, corel-paint-shop-pro

In Paint Shop Pro X9, after making a rectangular selection, is there a way to adjust the selection size? In Paint.NET and XnView you can grab the sides of the selection and drag them to make them bigger or smaller. This is a really neat feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add or subtract a piece from your selection. It is more powerful (=does the same and more, beyond that) than dragging an edge.

ADDENDUM due the comment:

Another way to work: Crop your image, but make a copy. The crop tool has handles. You can paste the cropped image onto a new layer over your original if needed.

The third way: Create a vector rectangle. It is adjustable. Use it with shape cutter. Now your selection has embedded into an original sized image at the original place. That is easy to reinstall after the processing.

Comment: Well, I still only want a rectangular selection. So, I would possibly need to "add" some amount to each of the four sides going by your method, which seems like more work.

Comment: @posfan12 sorry, no handles in the rectagular selection and no "edit the selection mode" as in Photoshop. Only workarounds, that are complex when compared to redrawing. See 2 more.